# IIS Rewrite URL cant match on hyphen

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a url in iis. Windows 8, iis 7, url rewrite 2.0.

I just want to rewrite any url with a hyphen. It only seems to work if the hyphen is the first character

If the url on my page is "mysite.com/-this-is-test-page" the below works.

```
  <match url="^(-)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="content/this-is-a-test.asp" />
```

But I can't seem to get this to work if the hyphen is not the leading character. I have tried every matching I can think of. I can match with a leading hyphen, but not a hyphen in the middle of the string.

None of these work:

```
^(/-)
^(\-)
^([-])
^([\-])
^([/-])
^([\-])
```

Comment: i left out  ^([\-]) I tried this too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the hyphen `-` alone. If you like to, you can also use it in a [character class `[-]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or a [capturing group `(-)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). In your case here, this does not really matter.

`^` is an anchor which [defines the beginning of a string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). If you are using `^` in front of the hyphen, you are saying, it should only match, if the hyphen is in the beginning.

*Sometimes, the hyphen needs to be escaped with a slash: `\-`*

Comment: getting there... <match url="(-)" /> does match! But... I can't seem to use the capture in the rewrite:
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="content/{R:1}.asp" />
I have tried R:0 also. And the captured value definitely matches the asp page that I am rewriting with.

Comment: You are actually capturing the hyphen and nothing else. It checks, if the hyphen is in there and then provides it as the first group. If you want capture anything else, you need to specify what..

Comment: Yes I see it is lookng for C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\mysite2.com\content\-.asp
I want the entire string... if it has a hyphen. I thought () did that.

Comment: Use `(.*-.*)` to capture everything (but require a dash). [See the live example here](https://regex101.com/r/fwIXx3/1). `()` just capture a group which is part of your match. If you e.g. want to match `st` out of `test` you can define the regex like that: `te(st)`. It will only match, if there is the full word `test` in it, but only return `st` as first group.

Comment: ahhh. Well, it works. I am so thankful for your help. As simple as this turned out to be, I spent an embarrassingly long time on it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: although one more question, not technical really--the reason i am looking to do this is to make nice looking urls. I keep content in "content" folder so its organized for me, but want it to show in the root for SEO and readability. If you look around quora.com, they are one example. But there are also pages that DO exist, physically, at the root. Pages like default, aboutus, etc. How do you differentiate? I decided to use no hyphen in any page but content and so my rule will only affect my content pages. Is that the "right" way or is there something better that I failed to see?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this topic. It's probably best if you ask another question here on StackOverflow.